# Where do I find driver installation info from a previous install

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, reinstall, file-location

I just tried to reinstall Windows XP on a new hard drive.  It installs and boots just fine, but now I can't get a lot of the built-in hardware working because I seem to have misplaced my motherboard driver CD.  This includes the Ethernet connector, without which I can't get online. (Posting from a different computer.)

Thing is, all those drivers were installed and working on my previous install, on the old hard drive, which is still connected to the computer.  The info for them has to be in `\Windows` somewhere, and I ought to be able to point the Add New Hardware wizard to it and have it just copy them over and set them up.  But I can't find where.  Does anyone know where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually located in

```
c:\windows\inf
```

However, I would personally look online at your motherboard manufacturers website so you can download the most up to date drivers. Most manufacturers will have them available or by going to sites such as [Intel](http://www.intel.com), [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw) etc. you can usually get the latest available.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Although it didn't show up at first because the folder's invisible and I hadn't set the setting for it yet.  (Also, it's kinda hard to go online and download drivers when your network adapter doesn't have a driver yet.)

Comment: As you were posting here, I thought you may have internet - but I understand, don't worry - FYI, you can use a USB stick to copy the driver from the machine you are on now, but no problem - if it works, it works, but as you are doing a fresh install, I would personally use the latest versions of everything.